# install kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64.rpm fails

Tags: linux, oracle

**While trying to install kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64.rpm I got following error :(**  Pls help, really in trouble

```
 [root@nonprodsrv02 kdumprpm]# rpm -ivh kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64.rpm

 warning: kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 1e5e0159
 error: Failed dependencies:
    mkinitrd >= 5.1.19.6-71.0.10 is needed by kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64
    oraclelinux-release is needed by kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64
    udev < 095-14.27.0.1.el5_7.1 conflicts with kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64
 [root@nonprodsrv02 kdumprpm]#
```

Comment: tried mkintrd instlallation(http://oss.oracle.com/ol5/SRPMS-updates/mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-71.0.10.el5_7.1.src.rpm), it succeed but still unable to run rpm.

Comment: Have you contacted Oracle support?

Comment: Thank you, 
any idea abt last line   udev < 095-14.27.0.1.el5_7.1 conflicts with kernel-uek-2.6.32-300.7.1.el5uek.x86_64

Comment: @mdpc - not really. Home users don't tend to install Oracle.

Comment: I solved the issue by applying an older version "rpm -iv --nodeps kernel-uek-2.6.32-200.13.1.el5uek.x86_64.rpm"
Beware to use rpm -iv --nodeps (since no dependency required for kdump installation)

Comment: can you post a solution if needed and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like:

1. the udev package should be upgraded.
2. The oraclelinux-release package needs to be installed
3. the mkinitrd package should be upgraded.

This is the problem using rpm straight on a single package and not using some type of packaging support system like yum which catches these issues and tries to address them.  I don't know what Oracle Linux supports in this area.